# Moodle ubuntu config.php

Tags: moodle

I must install Moodle on Ubuntu system and send server to the another location where I do not know which IP address will be acquired by DHCP. (Remote connection is restricted).
   without moving to this location it's possible to extract IP address acquired by DHCP, insert it into the config.php file, then resolve this IP to the hostname and make Cron job to launch this script whenever the server starts?
I would be happy if you suggest any solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Moodle has been designed with a fixed location, whether it uses the IP Address or the Server Name provided by the DNS Server. Without it Moodle will not be accessible. Moreover, the latest version of moodle (version 3.x and above) requires that access must use SSL / https.
I think this is related to the expected level of security.
Therefore, at least you need to make sure you can get a fixed URL, and install it in config.php.